# Проблема с Route::group

Tags: laravel, laravel7

Привествую. У меня есть раздел posts какой содержит базовые роутинги, решил добавить еще одно вложение posts/**trashed** но не могу до него достучатся.

Как было

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'],
    function () {       
        Route::resource('posts', 'BlogPostController', ['names' => 'admin.posts']);
    });
```

Пробую добавить trashed как еще одну глубину в posts где метод из BlogPostController нужна только одна фунция это **trashed**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'],
    function () {       
        Route::resource('posts', 'BlogPostController', ['names' => 'admin.posts']);

        Route::get('posts/trashed', ['uses' => 'BlogPostController@trashed',
            'as' => 'admin.posts.trashed']);
    });
```

Список маршрутов по методу выше

```
|        | POST      | admin/posts                      | admin.posts.store        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@store                    | web,auth  
                                           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts                      | admin.posts.index        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@index                    | web,auth  
                                           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/create               | admin.posts.create       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@create                   | web,auth  
                                           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/trashed              | admin.posts.trashed      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@trashed                  | web,auth  
                                           |
|        | DELETE    | admin/posts/{post}               | admin.posts.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@destroy                  | web,auth  
                                           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/{post}               | admin.posts.show         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@show                     | web,auth  
                                           |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/posts/{post}               | admin.posts.update       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@update                   | web,auth  
                                           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/posts/{post}/edit          | admin.posts.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\BlogPostController@edit                     | web,auth
```

отрывок из BlogPostController.php

```
 public function trashed()
    {

        $posts = $this->blogPostRepository->getAllWithPaginateTrash(5);

        return view('admin.posts.index', compact('posts'));

    }
```

Проблема в том что из **Route::group** не работает, выводит просто белую страницы без 404 ошибки, без каких-то других ошибок и дебаг не работает на этой странице. Выношу за пределы group вот таким способом то все работает, данные приходят те какие жду по ссылки

```
Route::get('posts/trashed', ['uses' => 'Admin\BlogPostController@trashed',
                'as' => 'admin.posts.trashed']);
```

Но я хочу чтоб он в Route::group сидел и только один маршрут строился с trashed.

Как сделать это ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте ваш роут перед `resource`.

```
Route::get(
    'posts/trashed', 
    [
        'uses' => 'BlogPostController@trashed',
        'as' => 'admin.posts.trashed'
    ]
);
```

Ваш запрос сначала попадает в `resource` и не находит страницу `posts/trashed` и выдает ошибку 404. До `GET` после него, он не доходит.